# Android Retrofit failure()

Tags: java, android, web-services, retrofit

Hello I am trying to make an app that will get the lat long from web url

http://akshay.site90.net/getLats.php?username=rakesh

And result will be in the form

```
{"lat":"30.1328064900","longitude":"77.2865304300"}
```

I am doing this using Android Retrofit..
But When I am opening the app the **failure()** of retrofit is called everytime but not the **success()**
I dont know what is going wrong..
it should call **onSucces()**

```
interface  api.java
package com.example.akshay.parentapp;

    import retrofit.http.GET;

    /**
     * Created by Akshay on 9/8/2015.
     */
    public interface api {
        @GET("/getLats.php?username=rakesh")
        public void getData( retrofit.Callback<getGSONData> response);
    }
```

**getGSONData.java**

```
package com.example.akshay.parentapp;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 9/8/2015.
 */
public class getGSONData {

    @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
    public String lat;

    @SerializedName("longitude")
    @Expose
    public String longitude;

    public void getlat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Double setLat() {
        Log.e("====LAT", lat);
        return Double.parseDouble(lat);
    }

    public void getlongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Double setLong() {
        Log.e("====LONG", longitude);
        return Double.parseDouble(longitude);
    }

}
```

**Map.java**

```
package com.example.akshay.parentapp;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 8/31/2015.
 */
public class Map extends FragmentActivity {
    public final String URL = "http://akshay.site90.net";
    LatLng prev = null;
    LatLng current = null;
    int flag = 0;
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
      LocationManager  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.e("OnLocationChanged" , "===========0");
                RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(URL).build();
               api api = restAdapter.create(api.class);
                api.getData( new Callback<getGSONData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(getGSONData getGSONData, Response response) {
                        Double LAT = getGSONData.setLat();
                        Double LONG = getGSONData.setLong();
                        current =  new LatLng(LAT , LONG);

                       Log.e("===LAT" , String.valueOf(LAT));
                        Log.e("===LONG" , String.valueOf(LONG));
                         if (flag == 0 & LAT!=null & LONG != null)
                         {
                             prev = current;
                             flag = 1;
                         }
                        CameraUpdate cm = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current, 18);

                        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                        polylineOptions.color(Color.RED).add(prev,current).width(20).visible(true);
                        googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                        googleMap.animateCamera(cm);
                        prev = current;
                        current = null;


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
Log.e("====" , "Something gone wrong");
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I do have both permissions in the manifest files

Comment: Something wrong with your naming convention - class is named as method, package referencing, getters are named as setters and vise versa

Comment: just to clarify, why are you making a network call inside onLocationChanged any particular reasons?

Comment: I am just trying to call it via LocationListener .. But I have also removed the whole location Stuff but still same happens

Answer (score 4):

print

```
t.getCause()
```

in onFailed and let me know to help you

Answer (score 2):

I can see a few things that could cause some issues:

1) Your web API returns the data as 'text/html', not as 'application/json', so Retrofit might not be able to read it correctly.

2) Try and add a '/' at the end of your base URL, so it looks like this:

```
public final String URL = "http://akshay.site90.net/";
```

3) Your setter/getters are wrong in the 'getGSONData' class. Your getters are setting the values and your setters are getting the values.

Comment: I have done changed what you said but still same issue

Comment: you just saved my life from 6 years ago

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All For your support

The Web URL Was returning

```
{"lat":"30.1329624300","longitude":"77.2864860400"}
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

So I cleared the In Activity Adds from my free hosting 000.webhost.com
And that works

Answer (score 0):

in retrofit2 u can do it easily like this :

1. in your interface,  Api.class :

   ```
   public interface Api {  
     @GET("/getLats.php")
     Call<List<getGSONData>> getData(@Query("username") String username);
   }
   ```
2. in your Service class, let say ServiceGenerator.class :

   ```
   public class ServiceGenerator {

     public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://your.api-base.url";

     private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

     private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
       new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

     public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
       Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
       return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
     }
   }
   ```
3. And in your activity, to calling asynchronously use enqueue :

   ```
    //prepare variable to contain result
    List<getGSONData> resultList;

    //create service
    Api myApi = ServiceGenerator.createService(Api.class);

    //instantiate the call and set parameters
    Call<List<getGSONData>> call = myApi.getData("rakesh");

    //enqueue for doing asynchronous, if you want to synchronous use 
    //execute().body() with try catch:
    //
    // resultList = call.execute().body();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<getGSONData>>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Response<List<getGSONData>> response, 
             Retrofit retrofit) 
      {
            // handle success 
            //code 200 ..300
            if(response.isSuccesful())
              resultList = response.body();
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable t) 
      {
         // handle failure
      }
    });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your setter and getter methods wrong, check it out. it should be like

```
public void setlat(String lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public Double getlat() {
    Log.e("====LAT", lat);
    return Double.parseDouble(lat);
}
```

Try to use `addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` in retrofit so that it values can be directly mapped to your `POJO` class.

```
private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use or call `Call<ResponseBody>` instead of the object that you have created to show all the JSON string and make sure that everything works fine before you check your code because that may not be showing in Postman or online sites.